# Change any form of date time string format into US date time format using C++

Tags: c++

Change any form of date time string format into US date time format using C++
example
format 1: dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy  h:mm:ss tt
format 2: dd MMMM yyyy  h:mm:ss tt 
format 3: MM/DD/YYYY at HH:mm:ss

All above format must get converted and printed into below given format 
dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy   h:mm:ss tt (this is US time format)

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: hey currently i am manually converting and inserting it into DB

Comment: i guess epoc time converter can also be a good solution. but how do i execute it when multiple datetime format are involved

Answer (score 1):

Since all the example formats are different (e.g. the occurrence of commas, spaces, or slashes), you could try to identify the input format by checking for the format-specific characters:

```
std::string inputDate = "Wed, 31 Mar, 2016 10:28:00";
if (inputDate.find(",") < std::string::npos) handleFormat1();
else if (inputData.find("/") < std::string::npos) handleFormat3();
else handleFormat2();
```

where the functions `handleFormat` would do the conversion from the input format to your desired output format.

Of course, if you have to deal with a larger number of input formats it will be more complicated to identify the correct format or the days, months, years, and times. But since you can do it manually it should also be possible to figure it out for all possible formats.

Comment: overall there are 71 format and it would be very difficult to put condition on each individual format

Comment: That is true. But I do not think that there is a simple solution of that problem (unless somebody else already solved it ....). Maybe you can try to first divide the string into numbers, day/month names, and separators. In a next step you can try to figure out the meaning of the different numbers (i.e., only the year is 4 digits, days are always smaller than 31, ...).